# PHP $_SESSION, trying to access users table displays no output and when session is killed the session remains active

Tags: php

i'm trying to a build a secure sessionID.
Usually i store the UserID as the `$_SESSION['session'];`, now im not too sure if it is really secure to have the userID as the sessionID. so what i have done is tested this theory although now i cannot access the users information and after i kill the session the sessions are still active and available?

CODE to check login if true or false:

```
if(password_verify($userPass, $user['userPasswd']))
{
    session_start();
    $UID = str_replace($user['text'].$user['text1'], '', $user['uniqID']);
    $_SESSION['SESSION'] = sha1(md5(sha1($UID)));
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Logout Script: EDIT fixed using $_SESSION = array();

```
public function userLogout()
{
     session_destroy();
     unset($_SESSION['SESSION']);
     return true;
}
```

Script to access users table information (username, email etc):

```
$userID = $_SESSION['SESSION'];
$stmt = $userClass->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uniqID=:userID");
$stmt->execute(array(":userID"=>$userID));
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($_SESSION['SESSION']); //Prints out session even if not logged in 
print $user['Username']; //Prints out nothing
```

i'm not sure if i missed a step or if hashing a session is even necessary, maybe i am doing something incorrectly. Essentially i am trying to secure the userID via a hash instead of having it displaying the users actual ID. Using the hash i would like to match and gain access to the users column.

ADDITIONAL NOTE: if i change the session to get the actual userID eg: 1

```
$userID = 1; //i did set the $_SESSION var to the userID to check if logout works
$stmt = $userClass->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=:userID");
$stmt->execute(array(":userID"=>$userID));
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($_SESSION['SESSION']); //prints out 1 //still does not destroy session after userLogout() is initiated 
print $user['Username']; //Prints username which is correct
```

been boggled by this for hours, maybe a different set of eyes and experience might help x_x.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What do you mean by a "secure" session ID? The session is private to the current user, unless someone hacks into the server and can read the RAM, in which case you have got bigger problems. What problem are you trying to solve? `sha1(md5(sha1($UID)));` seems a bit overkill as well? session_destroy() should clear the session values, although you may need to explicitly clear it from memory as well with `$_SESSION = array();` and possibly clear cookies as well if you want to be really thorough.

Comment: https://7php.com/php-5-3-how-to-completely-destroy-session-variables-in-php/

Comment: @ADyson yes i have fixed the session_destroy(). It was being executed. basically instead of setting the users ID as the session variable i created a uniq id  to set a session. with that uniqID i have hashed it using `sha1(md5(sha1($UID)));` although now it does not seem to want to get the users data in that column. if i set the users ID as the session var then it displays  the users column data if i call the var `$user['username'];`

Comment: yes but my question really was _why_ you want to do all that? Why do you feel the need to hash it (let alone triple-hash it including one hash method (md5) which is well known to be insecure anyway). I'm not clear what benefit you think this brings you?

Comment: @ADyson i am basically making this site to hold confidential data and i HAVE to clear everything as i cannot keep any traces left after  a session is killed, I cannot use the userID to locate the tables as it could be a vulnerability so i want to substitute it with a hash that cannot located the userID or how many users there are in total.

Comment: the md5 was just added recently so that i could test if i could decrypt the final hash down to the uniqID

Comment: I'm not questioning the need to clear the session after a logout, that's definitely a good idea, I'm questioning why you think holding the user ID in the session is insecure. Who is going to steal it, and how?

Comment: i feel that exposing the userID in a superglobal PHP variable ($_SESSION) is a bit sketchy if you get what i'm saying lol

Comment: feeling something might be "sketchy" does not make it actually a vulnerability. Why go to all the effort without any evidence? The session is private to the current user, you shouldn't need to worry.

Comment: Im more of a perfectionist, so i like to be 100% sure that all entry points are secure. i have read that the session is private but that is not enough to stop someone who really wants access.
i can say it is really overkill though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this is a comment, but its a bit long)

As ADyson says, this is very confused coding. Neither your code nor your narrative explain what you are trying to achieve here. What is the threat model? What is your definition of "secure"? `$_SESSION['SESSION']` is not [the session id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php).

If you store a static map between the (effectively random, but not random enough) identifier stored in the session and the username, then all you've done is limit the performance and scalability of the system - I cannot see how it adds any value for security.

There is a usage model where you might want a warrant-proof user database, where you would hash usernames - but this is not it.

There are models for protecting the session data from other subscribers on a shared host (with poor partitioning). This is not that either.

There are models for ensuring that session data is protected in backups....and, nope, this isn't very good for that either.

> sha1(md5(sha1($UID)));

This is silly.

Take some time to understand how the default session handler actually works before you start trying to improve it by throwing code at it (hint: there are things in there which are not suitable for every application, but if you want to improve them, [use a custom handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) - not wrapping the default handler in additional code). But before you write any code, you need to get your head around exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: well i would not say this is entirely dumb `sha1(md5(sha1($UID)));` the md5() addition probably is. what i want to accomplish: users table has a uniqID (nametest`9237692456`) i remove the nametest using str_replace then i hash the uniqid so that i can set it as the `$_SESSION['SESSION']` which produces something like this `ffb48afd7ef79e0569f8771049f586ca5` now the part where i  was stuck at is that the session does not recognize the session `ffb48afd7ef79e058e000e769f8771049f586ca5` because the uniqID is now hashed and does not match anything in the database so it will return a NULL value

Comment: if i had to call the users username using `$user['Username']`, the part i am stuck at is how would i get that hash value to match with the database uniqID. i  am attempting a fix where i add a sessionID table for the user so that when the hash value is set on the session it can call the column sessionID and then theoretically should match if i post the next hash every time the user logs in. I will get back to you with benchmarks and you can see if its going to bottleneck the system if i have 1k + users

Comment: @JamesBond "i add a sessionID table for the user so that when the hash value is set on the session it can call the column sessionID and then theoretically should match if i post the next hash every time the user logs in.". Originally you said the purpose of the hashing was to stop the UserID in the session being (in some unstated way) used to identify the user records in the database. If you simply create another column which matches the hash, then you've negated that protection entirely. Hashes are not reversible (unlike encryption), which is why you've got that issue.

Comment: @JamesBond but this answer is really trying to explain to you, as I have been doing, that you simply don't need to do this at all, it doesn't improve your security, it just obfuscates your data and causes you practical problems, as you've discovered. In any case, the user ID, on its own, isn't much use to anyone, unless they already have access to the database...but if they already have access to the database, they can already read _all_ of your data anyway, not just this user's. It's a totally pointless endeavour to try and hide it.

Comment: @ADyson You have a valid point, after some research and i found that your information is correct and that it is a bit overkill. what i was planning to do was insert the hash into the column on user login and remove it on logout. Then again, like you said no one can really do anything without direct access and if they do have direct access its a much bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow such way:

```
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

Comment: that worked to kill the session, although the  hashed version of the session still does not match the hash of the initial uniqID. Which means it still does not display the users table/column .

Comment: You have the UID by which you are trying to retrieve record should be matched with database record. For example you have made hash code like $test = md5('test'); which is inserted into your database  and trying to retrieve data using same pattern "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE name =".md5('test')

Comment: @ShariatHossain Valid point. i think that the session hash might not be correctly matching up with the users table data which would lead to displaying no data. going to check if they are matching up correctly

Comment: yes it did help, although its not the complete answer. I will add you into the complete answer :)